# Make larger or smaller a hexagonal based on percentage (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an hexagonal points as follows:

```
Points =
2.0000    3.0000
1.1340    2.5000
1.1340    1.5000
2.0000    1.0000
2.8660    1.5000
2.8660    2.5000
```

Then I plotted this points as follows:
[image: Hexagonal]

Now, I want to make it 80% smaller and put the smaller one into the original hexagonal with different color.

Similarly, I want to repeat this original hexagonal shape with a 140% larger size.

Is there any function in MATLAB to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hexagon seems to be centered at [2,2]. So you could subtract the center, scale, and then add back the center, like this:

```
center = ones(6,1)*[2,2];
Points_scaled = (Points - center) * scale + center;
```

where scale = 0.8 to shrink and 1.4 to enlarge. Plot Points_scaled the same way you plotted points. To change the color, use, e.g., `plot(..., 'Color',the_color)` where `the_color` could be a characer ('r','k','g',...) or an RGB triplet ([0,0,1], ...).

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there's no function that scales points, but this is easy enough to do manually by subtracting the center, then scaling the points, then adding the center back in.

Example:

```
points = [ ...
    2.0000    3.0000
    1.1340    2.5000
    1.1340    1.5000
    2.0000    1.0000
    2.8660    1.5000
    2.8660    2.5000];

% Translate so center is at 0,0
centerx = mean(points(:,1));
centery = mean(points(:,2));

points0 = points;
points0(:,1) = points0(:,1) - centerx;
points0(:,2) = points0(:,2) - centery;

% Scale
points1 = points0 * 0.80;
points2 = points0 * 1.40;

% Translate back to original center
points1(:,1) = points1(:,1) + centerx;
points1(:,2) = points1(:,2) + centery;
points2(:,1) = points2(:,1) + centerx;
points2(:,2) = points2(:,2) + centery;

% Plot results
figure(); hold on;
plot(points([1:end 1],1), points([1:end 1],2), '-b');
plot(points1([1:end 1],1), points1([1:end 1],2), '-r');
plot(points2([1:end 1],1), points2([1:end 1],2), '-k');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shrinkfaces`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shrinkfaces.html):

```
% the original patch:
p1 = patch(Points(:,1),Points(:,2),'w','EdgeColor','b')
% reduce p1 by 80%:    
p2 = shrinkfaces(p1,0.2)
patch(p2,'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','g')
% enlarge p1 by 140%:
p3 = shrinkfaces(p1,1.4)
patch(p3,'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','r')
```

[image: ShrinkPatch]